# node-webkit: issue on taking e.target from mousedown

Tags: javascript, jquery, node-webkit

In node-webkit, I was running the code like below.

Jquery

```
$(document).on('mousedown', '.clickOnMe', function(e){
  console.log(e.target);
});
```

I noticed that it taking few mili seconds to access to e.target and you feel like there is some lag/freeze when using the application. My application contains access to e.target and wonder if there is any better way that doesn't lag or freeze. The lag is like 0.1 sec.

I've tried using pure JavaScript but the output was the same.

---

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<meta charset=utf-8 />
</head>
<script src="js/jquery/1.7.2.min.js"></script>
<style>
.clickOnMe { border: 1px solid black; height: 200px; width: 200px; background: #ddd;}
</style>
  <script type='text/javascript'>
  $(document).on('mouseup', '.clickOnMe', function(e){
    $('.clickOnMe').css('background','red');
  });

$(document).on('mousedown', '.clickOnMe', function(e){
  console.log(e.target);
  $('.clickOnMe').css('background','blue');
  });

$(document).on('mousemove', document, function(e){
  console.log(e.target);
  });

  </script>
<body>
  <div class='clickOnMe' >
    Click on me.
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

OldGeeksGuide, this is the code I used to test each platforms, node-webkit 0.9.x, 0.8.x, atom shell, brackets shell, chrome, etc. So far, node-webkit gives me the lag. Please take a look at console log and see how fast other ones shows the log. Im using Windows7. Thank you!

-Im using document.on but the performance is the same with pure JavaScript or $('id').on

Comment: How are you measuring it?  I'm not sure how you could notice 'a few milliseconds', but I just tried it on my mac with nw 0.8.4 and 0.9.2 and don't notice any problem.

Comment: What Im doing here is some kind of animation, and animation skips when I  access to e.target, ex. console.log(e.target).

Comment: Ah, that's a little different.  Have you tried it in Chrome or another webkit/blink based browser?  How does the performance compare?  can you post a more complete test case to illustrate the problem?

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I tried chrome and no problem at all, also atom shell, brackets shell didnt show the lag with the same code. So far, I have this lag from node-webkit only.

Comment: Ill edit my post to add the code